# Jersey. POJO with arrays return 415 unsupported media type

Tags: java, jersey

Here is my POJO

```
public class AllParticipantsDTO {

private List<SubmissionParticipantDTO> hairStylists;
private List<SubmissionParticipantDTO> mds;
private List<SubmissionParticipantDTO> muas;
private List<SubmissionParticipantDTO> phs;
private List<SubmissionParticipantDTO> setDesigner;
private List<SubmissionParticipantDTO> wardrobeStylists;
```

Which contains arrays of:

```
public class SubmissionParticipantDTO {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private CountryDto country;
private String city;
private Boolean me;


@POST
@Path("init")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response initSubmission(final AllParticipantsDTO allParticipantsDTO) {
```

I don't get why i'm getting 415. 
I've also tried to add jersey-media-json-jackson to pom, still same issue

Comment: Are you setting the header to `application/json` in the header?

Comment: sure, i'm using Postman for testing and body like {
 "hairStylists": [],
 "mds": [],
 "muas": [],
 "phs": [],
 "setDesigner": [],
 "wardrobeStylists": []
}

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console/logs? Ideally if you are setting the correct  content type this shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check, in this order. You say you checked those things, so I really think it's probably the GET vs POST. But anyways, double-check these three yet again, just in case:

1. Make sure that you have already set the appropriate header, i.e. Content- 
   Type="application/json; charset=utf8"
2. Make sure that the JSON object can be properly deserialized, i.e.
   pay attention to lower and upper casing and also pay attention
   whether i.e. a field setDesigner really IS an (empty) array and you just
   consider it as a regular object (I am emphasizing this due to your
   naming practice of that particular array)
3. Make sure that your route/path AND request type (I see @POST there) is correct.

Although it could be that there's some misspelling or that your JSON object simply isn't valid because it lacks some obligatory fields, I guess you already double-checked it already, so **if I had to make a wild guess, I think it's because you keep sending i.e. a GET request instead of a POST**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was in POJO itself. 
The SubmissionParticipantDTO had extra parameter in few arrays, so jersey couldn't handle it.